# How to make responsive break points content with bootstrap or pure css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, frontend

I want to make a responsive content with bootstrap "row" and "col" class. But I got a problem how to reconstructure the content. Here's what I mean :

[image: Responsive]

My current html structure is this :

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <section id="content1">
            Content 1
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <section id="content2">
            Content 2
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <section id="content3">
            Content 3
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code showing the reverse of above content (when below than 768px). so the Content 3 was Content 2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to apply [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to your second and third elements. Ordering is built into Bootstrap 4, so you can simply make use of the `order-` prefix. As such, you simply want to apply `order-2` to your second `<div>` and `order-1` to your third.

This can be seen in the following:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <section id="content1">
      Content 1
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 order-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <section id="content2">
      Content 2
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-9 order-1 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <section id="content3">
      Content 3
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
      Div 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-8 order-md-4 order-sm-1">
      Div 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 order-sm-2">
      Div 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Change the visual order of specific flex items with a handful of order utilities. Bootstrap provides options for making an item first or last, as well as a reset to use the DOM order.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/
Check this link for reference